# Ubuntu mail server, stopped posting mail to public servers

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I've set up postfix on my ubuntu local server for internet mail.

Up till now, I was sending emails via the local machine that was accepted into gmail, comcast, yahoo, and etc mail systems.

But, for some reason now, it randomly stopped pushing out those emails, except for my local network.

I double checked to see if my IP was blocked / spam block listed, but all blockers came back negative.

Any idea? Maybe something in the config went crazy.  Even the mail.log and such weren't showing updates, yet my local mail runs through fine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you table to telnet to port 25 of any of those hosts? If you're on a standard cable/DSL ISP, many of them will block access to "foreign" mail servers as a spam prevention measure. You may be able to get the ISP to exempt you from this policy, but you may have to relay your mails through their own SMTP server instead.

Comment: Yes, I can telnet in and mail out; but the mail is never received on the WAN end.  However, prior today to WAN worked.

Comment: Anything in your local mail server's logs? If the mail are being rejected for some reason at any level, your mail server will show why and the mails would be stuck in your outgoing queue for a few days (`mailq` command would show them sitting there).

Comment: woah ,yes mailq show's a handful of sitting emails.  They all say "Connection timed out" (for the ones being sent to external host i.e. gmail)

Comment: i'm not sure why my mail.log / mail.err / etc aren't being updated either

Comment: Is the SMTP server running? Local mail can be delivered even if postfix/sendmail/exim aren't running.

Comment: Yea, the SMTP is running, i'm able to connect and HELO; response is good.

Comment: When I mail via Telnet, the response (after submitting ".") is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXXXX

Comment: Then something's preventing your mail server from talking to the outside world. Bad firewall rule, perhaps?

Comment: Alright, I figured out why my logs weren't going through, I modified the ownership.. It looks like it's running normal; after pushing hte msg it shows removed; i'm guessing that means it's pushed

Comment: May  6 17:08:38 ubuntu-micro-server postfix/qmgr[4626]: A2FEB50059F: from=<root@***.com>, size=517, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  6 17:08:38 ubuntu-micro-server postfix/local[5479]: A2FEB50059F: to=<michael@***.com>, relay=local, delay=0.84, dela$
May  6 17:08:38 ubuntu-micro-server postfix/qmgr[4626]: A2FEB50059F: removed

Comment: btw, doing mailq, show's more messages sitting (Connection Timed Out)

Comment: removed means it's been taken out out of the queue, but you'd have to check as to exactly why. it can be successfully delivered, or it could've been in the queue so long it's been bounced back to the sender with "unable to deliver". the sample looks ok, though.

Comment: Yup, following hte logs through: May  6 17:23:33 ubuntu-micro-server postfix/smtp[5649]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[***]:25: Connection timed out; it sounds like my ip is blocked via gmail?

Comment: Log in to your server, and try `telnet smtp-in.l.google.com 25`. If that doesn't connect, then you've got a firewall issue somewhere. Either on your server, somewhere farther upstream at your ISP, or google's blocking you. Repeat the test for a yahoo server and any other place you'd be mailing to. I'm guessing it's comcast blocking outgoing SMTP to anything but their own SMTP server.

Comment: Yea, it's stuck trying to connect.  I'm going to check the router, but most likely it's comcast.  I wonder if they caught my output and blocked it.